# NPE in dataflow pipeline at SourceOperationExecutor.isSplitOperationTooLargeForDataflowService

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My dataflow pipeline had been running fine till the last run. Today when I ran it on a new dataset, I started getting NullPointerException. The problem is that the exception does not seem to be coming from my code (anywhere in the stacktrace) as can be seen below-

Is this a bug in dataflow framework or (as the exception seems to be happening in isSplitOperationTooLargeForDataflowService), this dataset, more precisely the split on it, is too large for dataflow?

Any help/insight would be much appreciated!

```
2016-07-04T16:27:00.044Z: Error:   (fb0b4effcb8800a6):    
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SourceOperationExecutor.isSplitOperationTooLargeForDataflowService(SourceOperationExecutor.java:100)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SourceOperationExecutor.isSplitResponseTooLarge(SourceOperationExecutor.java:92)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:227)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:146)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:164)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:145)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:132)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Could you provide the SDK version that you are running, and a sample job ID?

Comment: Job-id 2016-07-04_09_19_14-7168591499478192464, sdk version -
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.86

alpha 2015.10.08
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
core 2015.11.06
core-nix 2015.09.03
gcloud 
gsutil 4.15
gsutil-nix 4.14

Comment: It looks like the SDK version is very old; can you try updating to a more recent version (the latest is 1.6.0)?

Comment: Ran with the updated sdk - Dataflow SDK version: 1.2.1

Google cloud sdk is now 116.0.0 (as per gcloud --version). Still the same error - 
Submitted job: 2016-07-04_19_06_59-15551664626112502180

Comment: Apologies for not being more explicit; I'm asking if you can updating the Dataflow SDK version.

Comment: I did not know that dataflow sdk is outside google-cloud sdk. I am using eclipse plugin for cloud-dataflow which shows upto-date at version 1.2.1. Could you please tell me how to update the dataflow sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug that was fixed in the 1.4.0 release of the Dataflow SDK. As of this writing, the latest version of the SDK is 1.6.0.

It sounds like you are hitting an issue with the Eclipse plugin if it displays "up to date" at version 1.2.1. Your problems should be solved if you manually update your `pom.xml` to use version 1.6.0 of the SDK.

Comment: Maven project update after manual edit of pom.xml to use version 1.6.0 seems to be working. Thanks.